# How to download and open word file from cloud from side-loaded Task Pane Javascript Web Add-In for WORD

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm developing a Web Add-in using Office.js. And I need to download word file (docx file) from server and load the content to make changes in the Microsoft word. And I will need to re-upload the edited file as a new version of document to my server again.

I'm completely new with the Office.js Web Add-in development and I have no luck to find the example that match with my requirements. Please kindly refer me to a tutorial that implemented as my requirements. Any advise will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With very few exceptions, A Word web add-in lives in a universe in which there is only one Word document: the one that is currently open in Word where the add-in is running. You can't use and add-in to download another Word document or get content from another Word document.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential breach hole if add-ins start to download and run files from the internet. Instead, you may consider making a request to get the document content programmatically using a REST API call (if any) and then display it on the task pane.

Be aware, feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try to read the content using REST API call and try to reconstruct the contents in the current word file.